# Unknown component on PCB

Tags: identification, components

I am trying to reverse engineer a PCB and I found this component that I don't know what it could possibly be. It doesn't have any resistance (open circuit) and it doesn't have any capacitance. On the PCB it is labeled as Y4 and it is part of some sort of protective system between PE (ground) and 2 varistors connected to phase and neutral. Anyone got any clues what it could be? I could not find anything online with the markings on it which read "NEB R600XP5"

[image]

Comment: My best guess would be a MOV or similar gas discharge tube.

Comment: "the markings on it which read "NEB R600X""  It clearly reads "...00XP5" Did you leave out part of the text and why?

Comment: It's a gas discharge tube (GDT).

Answer (score 5):

It is a gas discharge tube, a GDT.

Comment: Yes you are correct. thank you